# Regex group excluding something a-z but not c

Tags: python, regex, email

I am making a regex expression which will match  .dom  .bom  .fom 
but NOT match  .com

Best I can do so far is:

```
r"\.[a-bd-z]om"
```

Any better way to do it ???

Comment: There is nothing wrong, per se, with your current regex.  What do you want to change, or what is the bigger problem here?

Comment: No, just wondering if there was any magic from the gurus.  I do have to write this out many many times for various other spelling pemutations, so just wanted to see if i could save some typing, before going ahead with this.

Comment: If your goal is to match chars a-z except for c, I would stay with your current pattern. It expresses exactly what you want to match without the need for lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your current regex:

```
r'\.[a-bd-z]om'
```

We could rewrite this as:

```
r'\.[^\Wc]om'
```

This would match any word character to start the domain, except for `c`.  You could also try using a negative lookahead:

```
r'\.(?!com)[a-z]om'
```

But, I actually prefer your current version, and wouldn't think to change it, unless there is a bigger problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You could either rewrite your current expression or use a function to test the matches afterwards:

```
import re

tests = ['.dom', '.bom', '.fom', '.com']

# alternative 1
pattern = re.compile(r"\.(?!c)[a-z]om")
tested = [test for test in tests if pattern.match(test)]
print(tested)

# alternative 2
pattern = re.compile(r"\.([a-z])om")

def aftertest(item):
    m = pattern.match(item)
    if m:
        return False if m.group(1).startswith("c") else True
    return False

tested = [test for test in tested if aftertest(test)]
print(tested)
```

Both approaches will yield

```
['.dom', '.bom', '.fom']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this:

```
import re

print(re.findall('\.[^c]om','bomcomnom.com.mom'))
```

Output:

```
['.mom']
```

Comment: Good, but matches a whole bunch of special characters, not just a-z

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try:

```
r"\.[a-z](?<!c)om"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Case - Insensitive Search you can use this

```
r"\.(?i)[a-bd-z]om"
```

For case - sensitive search you can use this:

```
r"\.[^(c|\d)]om"
```

Comment: The character class `[^(c|\d)]` matches any char that is not `(`, or `c` or `|`or  a digit or `)` and the pattern could possibly match `.^om`